# Elastic IP confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've set up an Amazon EC2 instance with my Rails app - http://ec2-54-235-85-12.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ - and I'm associating an elastic IP - 54.235.85.12 - with it (I'm hooking on to an API where I need a static IP, since so they can whitelist that IP).

Link is working and pointing to the app, but this is what I get when I check the address for the IP:

```
dig +short http://ec2-54-235-85-12.compute-1.amazonaws.com 
#67.63.55.3
```

But if I leave out the http://, then I get the correct IP:

```
dig +short ec2-54-235-85-12.compute-1.amazonaws.com
#54.235.85.12
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dig` is a DNS tool, it doesn't make sense to specify "http://" when calling it.  The erroneous result is likely due to some error when it attempts to parse the  bad input.  I'm not really understanding the problem here?

Comment: Problem is that I can't connect to the API that have whitelisted my Elastic IP and I'm not sure why. Any guesses?

Comment: @HolgerEdwardWardlowSindbæk login to the instance and run `curl ip.appspot.com`. Does it output the correct IP address?

Comment: I'm not sure what I did incorrectly. Getting things properly up and running with EC2 can be a bi***. I finally got it up and running properly, I SSH into it and did the curl ip.appspot.com, got the right IP and everything is working. Thanks for the clarification.